# How to fix 0x8027025a error when installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on WSL?

Tags: system-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lts, 22.04

The following [fail message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3SQ5.png) appeared when I tried installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on WSL. I'm not able to type anything, therefore, I'm not able to finish the set up.

Those are the [outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I750a.png) I'm getting from "wsl -l -o" and "wsl -l -v" commands.

This is the [Ubuntu-22.04 running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqdDM.png) after the failed installation.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Any progress?  I noticed [someone on Reddit had the same error code](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/uhu2gw/problems_installing_ubuntu_on_windows_10/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) (don't think it is you, since the error message is in a different language than what you posted), but no leads there either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is the same as Option 2 from @NotTheDr01ds, but eliminates the need to uninstall and reinstall the failed Ubuntu.  Much thanks to him, as I wouldn't have come up with this answer without insight gleaned from his answer.

1. Instead of uninstalling and re-installing, go to `Settings` > `Apps` > `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` > `Advanced Options` > **`Reset`**.  This seems to take you to the same state as the Ubuntu download being installed from the Microsoft Store but before it is unpacked.
2. `wsl --set-default-version 1`

```
The operation completed successfully.
```

3. **Now** start Ubuntu by clicking on the desktop or start menu icon to successfully start Ubuntu with WSL 1.
4. Exit the Ubuntu shell, then `wsl --shutdown`
5. `wsl -l -v`

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Stopped         1
```

6. `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2`

```
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Conversion complete.
```

7. `wsl --set-default-version 2`

```
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The operation completed successfully.
```

8. `wsl -l -v`

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Stopped         2
```

9. Start Ubuntu again and verify that it still works, now under WSL 2.

Comment: Cool - Thanks for the optimization!  Just curious, since I have no confirmation from anyone whether option 1 works or not -- Did you try it first?  And if so, what happened?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, the `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04` should get you to the same state, iirc, as a *Reset* via the GUI.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I did not try Option 1.

Comment: No worries - Was hoping.  I really think that's going to work and be the simplest solution, although hopefully Canonical just fixes the issues soon so folks don't run into the problem any longer ;-)

Answer (score 9):

*For those coming across this error, the following are several ideas to try to fix it:*

- Option 1:  Try this first.  Thanks to [@Silverfish](https://askubuntu.com/users/1625290/silverfish) for confirming that it works in a comment below.  This should be the easiest path to resolving *many* failed Ubuntu 22.04 WSL installations.
- Option 2:  From the comments, this seems to be a reliable way to fix the problem, but it's quite a bit longer than option 1.
- Options 3 and 4:  Only a fallback if the first two options aren't viable for you.*

###### Option 1:  Non-graphical install

From PowerShell:

- Unregister the existing 22.04 installation.  Note that this is a *destructive operation* and will remove all files in the distribution, so it should only be used on a failed installed or if you are otherwise confident that the distribution can be removed safely:

  ```
  wsl -l -v
  # Confirm the distribution name.
  # It should be either "Ubuntu-22.04" or
  # "Ubuntu" depending on when and how you
  # installed from the Store.
  # Update the commands below based on your version.

  wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04
  # or wsl --unregister Ubuntu
  ```
- Install 22.04 using the "old" non-graphical installer:

  ```
  ubuntu2204.exe install --ui=none
  # or ubuntu.exe install --ui=none
  ```

That should skip the problematic portion of the install and be successful.

###### Option 2: Install as WSL1, then convert to WSL2

Ubuntu 22.04 only uses the new TUI configuration step under WSL2.  I believe this step is what is failing with `The app didn't start in the required time.`.

Let's see if we can avoid that failure by installing as WSL1.  If that works, you can then convert to WSL2.

- Uninstall the failed Ubuntu 22.04, again (fun, I know)
- Reboot (optional, but recommended)
- From PowerShell, run:

  ```
  wsl --set-default-version 1
  ```
- Run the installer again.

Note that the installer will take much longer to run under WSL1.

If I'm right (and I know I haven't been so far), then this installer will complete successfully.  Note that it will skip the TUI configuration of the username/password, along with the optional `/etc/wsl.conf` step that it runs for WSL2.  It will go straight to the console-based username/password configuration.  Hopefully, this will allow you to enter it successfully.

If so, and the distribution comes up as your user, then:

- Exit Ubuntu
- Return to PowerShell and run:

  ```
  wsl -l -v
  # Confirm your distribution name, as in Option 1
  wsl --shutdown
  wsl --set-version Ubuntu-22.04 2
  # Or wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
  # This will take a while
  wsl --set-default-version 2
  wsl -l -v
  # Confirm the proper version
  ```

If this doesn't work for some reason, then move on to the next options ...

###### Option 3: Manually install the rootfs and create the correct user

You might be able to skip straight to the next step, but I'm including this one as the "safe" option of making sure that the rootfs is extracted properly.  Note that these instructions are for the "versioned" Ubuntu 22.04 version in the Store.  If you want to use the (now updated to 22.04) "Ubuntu" (without a version number), you'll need to make the appropriate modifications.

- Do *not* uninstall Ubuntu 22.04 this time
- Exit any WSL2 distribution
- Start an *Administrative* PowerShell and copy, paste, and run each line individually:

  ```
  # Edit paths below to your preference
  $WSL_IMAGE_PATH = "$env:USERPROFILE\WSL\Images"
  $WSL_INSTANCE_PATH = "$env:USERPROFILE\WSL\Instances"
  mkdir $WSL_IMAGE_PATH
  mkdir "$WSL_INSTANCE_PATH\Ubuntu-22.04"
  $UBUNTU_ROOTFS = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Canonical*22.04*' | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'install.tar.gz' })[0].FullName
  cp "$UBUNTU_ROOTFS" "$WSL_IMAGE_PATH\Ubuntu22.04.tar.gz"
  ```

  Exit the Administrative PowerShell
- Start a normal PowerShell and copy, paste, and run each line individually:

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  # Make sure these paths match those created above
  $WSL_IMAGE_PATH = "$env:USERPROFILE\WSL\Images"
  $WSL_INSTANCE_PATH = "$env:USERPROFILE\WSL\Instances"

  wsl --import Ubuntu2204 "$WSL_INSTANCE_PATH" "$WSL_IMAGE_PATH\Ubuntu22.04.tar.gz" --version 2
  ```

  If the image imports successfully, then `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu2204` to start it.

  You should have a similar startup screen that you show above -- You'll be logged in as the root user.

  Proceed to the next section (which can be done independently of this one).

###### Option 4: Manually create user

From within Ubuntu 22.04

```
read -p "Username: " NEWUSER
# Enter your desired username
adduser $NEWUSER
# This will create your username/password
usermod -aG  adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lxd $NEWUSER

# The following 4 lines must be entered together
cat <<EOF > /etc/wsl.conf
[user]
default=$NEWUSER
EOF

cat /etc/wsl.conf
# Confirm the contents
```

Exit Ubuntu, and from PowerShell:

```
# wsl -l -v
# Substitute "Ubuntu" as the distribution name below if needed
wsl --terminate Ubuntu-22.04
wsl ~ -d Ubuntu-22.04
```

If all went well, you should be in Ubuntu 22.04 as your default user.

Comment: I tried the "Install as WSL1, then convert to WSL2" solution, and it worked great. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasJonsson Excellent - Thanks for confirming!  Radio silence from the OP, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It worked great for me. Just wondering though, what's the point of the "Manually install the rootfs and create the correct user" and "Manually create user" steps? It seems to work fine for me after installing as WSL 1 version and converting to WSL 2? Am I missing something important?

Comment: @ChrisCrossCrash Those were just other ideas in case the conversion didn't work.  I'll edit the answer to make it more clear that the conversion seems to be working for most people.  The others may work as well, but conversion is probably easier.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for the clarification and the fast response! Everything continues to work fine.

Comment: Microsoft Store has separate "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu 22.04" apps, which currently both install Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL. I had the same error message when installing using the "Ubuntu" app. For anyone else trying the same thing, option 1 worked for me but needed the minor changes:
`wsl --unregister Ubuntu`
`ubuntu.exe install --ui=none`

Comment: @Silverfish That's a good point - The "unversioned" Store version of Ubuntu was just updated to 22.04 last week.  Many answers here will likely need to be updated as a result.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Cheers for editing to reflect this change! Have just checked & I get the same error message when trying to install from the "Ubuntu 22.04" app, and following option 1 sorts it out just like it did for me on the "Ubuntu" app. And of course `wsl -l -v`, the other bit you've added to your answer, did distinguish the two cases, so the updated answer all looks good! I'll just add that I'm on Windows 10, as I believe WSL can behave a bit differently on Windows 11. So if anyone reading this has hit the same error message in Windows 11 you may want to drop a comment saying if it worked for you or not!

Comment: Option 1: Non-graphical install worked for me

Answer (score 2):

*Note:  For others who come across this who are experiencing the `0x8027025a` error when installing Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL, please note that this answer did not solve the problem for the original poster.  I'm leaving it here since it has some background on how the installer works (for troubleshooting), but I would recommend trying my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406700/1165986) here first.*

---

I'm seeing similar failures (but not this exact error) now on my Windows 10 system (but not, so far, on my Windows 11 system).  It installed okay the first time, but after uninstalling and reinstalling (which I do often to try different things to answer questions) I've seen the same message.  Potential workarounds below (but no "solution" yet).

Some background -- Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL is the first *production* version to use the new "Ubuntu WSL Out-of-Box Experience" first seen in the [Community Preview](https://ubuntu.com/blog/announcing-ubuntu-on-windows-community-preview-wsl-2).  Previous WSL distributions installed from the Microsoft Store used a fairly simple, console-only installer (such as `ubuntu.exe`) that:

- Unpacked the rootfs tarball into the appropriate location in your `$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Packages\<package>` directory.
- Registered the distribution with WSL
- Ran the "initial configuration" stage which asked for the default username and password
- Registered the default username with WSL, which created the appropriate registry entries.

As far as I can tell, that's the order things occurred in.

The new Ubuntu 22.04 installer, on the other hand, seems to:

1. Start unpacking the tarball
2. Transitions to a graphical "Here's what's great about Ubuntu" rotating billboard.
3. Once the rootfs is extracted, registers the distribution with WSL
4. Transitions to a TUI (prettified, console menu) configuration stage where you can set your language, username, actual name, password.
5. Adds an additional TUI screen that will set some common `/etc/wsl.conf` options.
6. Registers the username with WSL
7. Writes any modified values to `/etc/wsl.conf`
8. Exits the TUI and launches the distribution as your user.

There are several possible failure points (and associated solutions), and probably some I don't know about yet:

###### Main potential workaround, if user is created

Note that this probably won't work for you, given the output you show in your question, but I'm keeping it here for others:

- In my case, I'm usually seeing the problem after Step 6 or 7.  When it does transition to the terminal, it *thinks* that something in the preceding steps hasn't completed successfully.  It then attempts to ask for the username and password using the "old method", which fails because it's already been set via the graphical installer.

  In this case, you can try closing the existing terminal window and relaunching via `wsl ~ -d Ubuntu-22.04`.  If it launches as root, check to see if your username exists in `/etc/passwd`.  If it does, set it to be the default by `sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf` and add the entries as specified in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833) (Method 1).
- I can also reproduce a slightly different failure by the *"Help"* option, but assuming it's late enough in the process, the same steps above can resolve.

###### Installer does not complete at all

- If the installer fails at an earlier step, you may need to start over.  Note that this will completely remove the distribution and all data, so (for other potential readers) **only do these steps if you have just installed and failed, with no existing data in Ubuntu 22.04**.

  1. Close all installer windows (and any other WSL instances)
  2. Go to PowerShell and:

     ```
     wsl --shutdown
     wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04
     ubuntu2004.exe
     ```
  3. The GUI will kick off again.  *Don't click anything*, even when it asks you if you can transition to the next step.  It should automatically proceed to `Willkommen! Bienvenue! Welcome! Добро пожаловать! Welkom!` where you can select your language.
  4. Do not, under any circumstance, select "Help" or the installer will crash again.  It may be recoverable, it may not be, but it *will* crash (in my experience).
  5. Do not use the mouse - This is *not* a graphical installer at this point -- It is a TUI and will only respond to the keyboard, AFAIK.
  6. Select your language in the TUI using the arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  7. Set your username/password in the TUI.  Select fields using <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  Once complete, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the *"Done"* and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  8. Unless you have a special need, don't change any options on the next screen.  *"Done"* should be selected by default.  Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  9. WAIT on the next screen that says *"Setup Complete"* and *"Applying Changes"* (conflicting information, IMHO).  This step takes far too long, and there's probably something broken "behind" it.  Again, do not select *"Help"* here, or the installer will not completely (in my experience).
  10. Eventually, it will transition to a *"Hi "* screen.  Take not of the instructions on updating, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the *"Reboot Now"* option.

Hopefully, that will transition to an regular shell at that point.

If not:

###### One final option

If the above fails, then try a full removal of Ubuntu 22.04 (but not WSL itself):

- Optional:  Run `RegEdit` in Windows, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`.  Find the entry under with the `DistributionName` of "Ubuntu-22.04" (exactly).
- Take note of it - Don't do anything else.  We just want to make sure it gets removed.
- Right click on *"Ubuntu 22.04"* in the Start menu and *"Uninstall"*.  Again, this will remove the distribution, so only do this if you have failed installation and have no data in it.  Also, please make sure you are removing the correct one - Don't, for instance, remove the wrong "Ubuntu" if you do have multiples installed.

  Note that, in the future, the "unversioned Ubuntu" in the Start menu will likely be 22.04 as well for new users (although hopefully these issues are resolved first).  Again, make sure you are removing the correct one.
- Back in RegEdit, *View* -> *Refresh* and confirm that the registry entry is gone.  If not, you may need to remove it manually.  Note that it *was* correctly removed for me.  I'm just anticipating a case where we really do need to make sure that everything is gone before reinstalling.
- Open File Explorer and navigate to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\`
- Look for one that starts with `CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS` (probably `CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc`).  If it doesn't exist, then fine.  Previous Ubuntu uninstallers did remove this directory.  But it *looks* like (at least for me) that the 22.04 uninstaller is leaving the virtual disk intact.  This is probably a good thing, since we've seen several questions here on AU where people lost data when uninstalling.

  But if it *does* still exist after uninstalling, you may want to remove the 22.04 directory manually.  You can, if you desire, back up the `..\LocalState\ext4.vhdx` file, but realize that it is about 1.5GB.
- With all of that complete, a reboot probably wouldn't be a bad idea.
- Then go back to the Microsoft Store and try reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 again, following the directions in the previous step.

Comment: I tried the "Installer does not complete at all" case, then the "One final options", and then the "Installer does not complete at all" again, twice, but sadly it did not work. I'm still getting the same installation fail message.

Comment: @LuanLima Bummer.  I do have one more way to install, but let me dust it off, test it against 22.04, and I'll write it up tomorrow.

Comment: @LuanLima Does `grep 1000 /etc/passwd` return anything in the failed install?

Comment: No, @NotTheDr0ids, `grep 1000 /etc/passwd` does not return anythnig.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be suitable for everyone. But in my case, having default app install location set to other drives than my system drive (C:) always gets me the same error. I also tried the classic way to install WSL on my D:\ drive by manually downloading and extracting it to a directory in this drive, only to encounter the same error.

[image: storage settings]

It's a bummer as I didn't want to load my C:\ drive with apps, but it is what it is. After cleaning up the faulty installation, setting it back to C:\ then installing Ubuntu 22.04 from MS Store allows me to fully setup the distro.

If you are low on space for your system drive, try the other answers first.

Comment: Good find -- Note that you can "move" it after installing by using the information in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1731302/1210833) (and others).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dhalsim2 for those informations.
At step 1, instead of "reset" I choose "repaired" it worked for me.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1244083)

Comment: Didn't work. I'm running winx64

Answer (score 0):

For me luckily I have PrimoCache software installed.

1. I started the cache for that particular drive.
2. Reset the Ubuntu app.
3. Start the app again. It'll finish the process including GUI.

Once you're done installing everything you can remove the drive from the primocache or even uninstall the software.
I think slow HDD affects the complete installation.

**EDIT:**

**LMAO I just now figured out the easiest way!**

1. Reset & repair your Ubuntu app.
2. Open Ubuntu app. It'll show installation dialog. **QUICKLY** close that and the background Ubuntu shell window once they pop up.
3. Open **PowerShell** type:

   ubuntu config --default-user yourname

It'll show up *Installing, this may take a few minutes...*
then finish the process by entering username & password.